# How can I get the MAX value of a column from a record or 0 if no record is matched in my SELECT?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that I use for insert. When I 
am inserting a record I would like the value of release
to be equal to one more than the highest value. So here
is what I coded:

```
    DECLARE @MaxRelease int;

    SELECT @MaxRelease = max(Release)
    FROM   dbo.Test
    WHERE  TestTypeId = @TestTypeId
    AND    ExamId     = @ExamId
    AND    Title      = @Title;

    INSERT ... @MaxRelease + 1 ... etc.
```

However how can I make this so that if there is nothing returned from the SELECT (because
there are no current records) that the value of @MaxRelease will be 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ISNULL (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) to replace a null value with a replacement value.

```
SELECT @MaxRelease = isnull(max(Release), 0)
FROM   dbo.Test
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign @MaxRelease an initial value of zero.

```
DECLARE @MaxRelease int = 0;

SELECT @MaxRelease = max(Release)
FROM   dbo.Test
WHERE  TestTypeId = @TestTypeId
AND    ExamId     = @ExamId
AND    Title      = @Title
GROUP BY TestTypeId;
```

If nothing is returned from the select, then @MaxRelease will not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DECLARE @MaxRelease int;

SELECT @MaxRelease = max(Release)
FROM   dbo.Test
WHERE  TestTypeId = @TestTypeId
AND    ExamId     = @ExamId
AND    Title      = @Title;

INSERT ... CASE WHEN @MaxRelease IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @MaxRelease + 1 END ... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**ISNULL**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms184325.aspx) Or [**COALESCE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190349.aspx)

like,

```
SELECT @MaxRelease = isnull(max(Release),0)
FROM   dbo.Test
WHERE  TestTypeId = @TestTypeId
AND    ExamId     = @ExamId
AND    Title      = @Title;
```

OR

```
if @MaxRelease is null
begin
set @MaxRelease =0
end

Then Execute Insert Query here.
```